# Programmatically add full size view in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working with a iMessage application and have programmatically added a view. However I can't seem to work out the correct constraints for making it the correct size at all times. For example, the view moves down a few hundred px if I leave the extension for another and come back to it. I think this has something to do with the .isActive. My goal is to make the view automatically resize to always be the right size or take up the full available height and width.

```
func createBrowser() {
    let controller = MSStickerBrowserViewController(stickerSize: .small)
    addChildViewController(controller)
    view.addSubview(controller.view)

    controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    controller.stickerBrowserView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    controller.stickerBrowserView.dataSource = self

    view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: controller.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: controller.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: controller.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: controller.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    view.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: controller.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    view.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: controller.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

Screenshot: https://d17oy1vhnax1f7.cloudfront.net/items/1F2B0s3v0s1k3E2L0Z07/Screen%20Shot%202016-09-19%20at%2011.42.51%20AM.png

Comment: This may be a silly question/I might not be reading your code correctly but have you got your constraints the wrong way around? Should you not be setting the constraints for the new view based on the constraints for the old view? It looks to me as though you are setting constraints for your parent controller's view based on the new child controller's view.

Comment: @Sparky you mean like this? controller.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true. I did that and the behavior is the same.

Comment: @Sparky? Sorry, I'm relatively new to iOS dev. Lil' help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

to better explain things I've put together the following. This demonstrates two methods of fixing the layout for subviews. When using constraints, I prefer to create the constraints as an array and activate them all in one go, as you will see in the code for createredSquareWithConstraints. A constraint is simply a linear equation relating the features of one view to that of another. In "pseudocode", for example, the first constraint in my array could be written:

"Set the leading margin of the subview equal to 1 times the leading margin of the container view plus a constant of 0."

(This is why I was getting confused earlier as it looked to me as though you were setting the containing view's constraints based on the characteristics of one of its subviews.)

While it remains perfectly valid to use layout constraints, I think the preferred methodology these days is to override the viewWillTransitionToSize() delegate method, which simply asks you to specify, given a size for the containing view, what the frame of a view controller's subviews should be. As such, I've included an implementation of this too, creating a yellow square with an initial frame that is then modified whenever viewWillTransitionToSize is called. I personally find this a lot less fiddly that using layout constraints.

If you lay around with the buttons and rotate the screen you should see that either method achieves the same thing. [NB I have labelled one square as constrained and one as unconstrained, but in reality they are of course both constrained, just in different ways. I would add that this is clearly not how you would do things in practice - you should choose one methodology and stick to it otherwise your code will be all over the place!].

Hope that helps!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var constrainedredSquare : UIView!
    var unconstrainedRedSquare : UIView!
    var methodOneButton : UIButton!
    var methodTwoButton : UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

        func getButton(name: String) -> UIButton {
            let button : UIButton = UIButton()
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            button.layer.cornerRadius = 3
            button.clipsToBounds = true
            button.setTitle(name, for: UIControlState.normal)
            button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: UIControlState.normal)
            return button
        }

        self.methodOneButton = getButton(name: "Red - Constraints")
        self.methodTwoButton = getButton(name: "Yellow - viewWillTransitionToSize")

        self.methodOneButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.createRedSquareWithConstraints), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.methodTwoButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.createYellowSquareWithoutConstraints), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.methodOneButton.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 100), size: CGSize(width: 300, height: 300))
        self.methodTwoButton.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width - 500, y: 100), size: CGSize(width: 300, height: 300))
        self.view.addSubview(self.methodOneButton)
        self.view.addSubview(self.methodTwoButton)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        if let _ = self.unconstrainedRedSquare {
            self.unconstrainedRedSquare.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size)
        }
        self.methodOneButton.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 100), size: CGSize(width: 300, height: 300))
        self.methodTwoButton.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: size.width - 500, y: 100), size: CGSize(width: 300, height: 300))
    }


    func createYellowSquareWithoutConstraints() {
        if let _ = self.unconstrainedRedSquare {
            self.unconstrainedRedSquare.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        else
        {
            if let _ = constrainedredSquare {
                self.constrainedredSquare.removeFromSuperview()
            }
            self.unconstrainedRedSquare = UIView()
            self.unconstrainedRedSquare.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
            self.unconstrainedRedSquare.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: self.view.frame.size)
            self.view.addSubview(self.unconstrainedRedSquare)

            self.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.methodOneButton)
            self.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.methodTwoButton)
        }

    }

    func createRedSquareWithConstraints() {
        if let _ = self.constrainedredSquare {
            self.constrainedredSquare.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        else
        {
            if let _ = self.unconstrainedRedSquare {
                self.unconstrainedRedSquare.removeFromSuperview()
            }
            let redSquare : UIView = UIView()
            redSquare.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

            self.view.addSubview(redSquare)

            self.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.methodOneButton)
            self.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.methodTwoButton)

            let rsConstraints : [NSLayoutConstraint] = [NSLayoutConstraint(item: redSquare, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
                                                 NSLayoutConstraint(item: redSquare, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
                                                 NSLayoutConstraint(item: redSquare, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
                                                 NSLayoutConstraint(item: redSquare, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
                                                 NSLayoutConstraint(item: redSquare, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
                                                 NSLayoutConstraint(item: redSquare, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)]
            redSquare.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(rsConstraints)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use my extension to `UIView`. It allows to add extra padding on any side (only if you want to):

```
public extension UIView {
    typealias ConstraintsTupleStretched = (top:NSLayoutConstraint, bottom:NSLayoutConstraint, leading:NSLayoutConstraint, trailing:NSLayoutConstraint)
    func addSubviewStretched(subview:UIView?, insets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets() ) -> ConstraintsTupleStretched? {
        guard let subview = subview else {
            return nil
        }

        subview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(subview)

        let constraintLeading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: subview,
                                                   attribute: .Left,
                                                   relatedBy: .Equal,
                                                   toItem: self,
                                                   attribute: .Left,
                                                   multiplier: 1,
                                                   constant: insets.left)
        addConstraint(constraintLeading)

        let constraintTrailing = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self,
                                                    attribute: .Right,
                                                    relatedBy: .Equal,
                                                    toItem: subview,
                                                    attribute: .Right,
                                                    multiplier: 1,
                                                    constant: insets.right)
        addConstraint(constraintTrailing)

        let constraintTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: subview,
                                               attribute: .Top,
                                               relatedBy: .Equal,
                                               toItem: self,
                                               attribute: .Top,
                                               multiplier: 1,
                                               constant: insets.top)
        addConstraint(constraintTop)

        let constraintBottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self,
                                                  attribute: .Bottom,
                                                  relatedBy: .Equal,
                                                  toItem: subview,
                                                  attribute: .Bottom,
                                                  multiplier: 1,
                                                  constant: insets.bottom)
        addConstraint(constraintBottom)
        return (constraintTop, constraintBottom, constraintLeading, constraintTrailing)
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
view.addSubviewStretched(tableView)

let BorderedBackgroundInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 1, left: 1, bottom: 1, right: 1)
view?.addSubviewStretched(calendar.view, insets: BorderedBackgroundInset)
```

Comment: Had to adjust the code in the constraints to meet the latest version of swift but this worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Getting this message "Result of call to 'addSubvieStretched(subview:insets:)' is unused. What's that mean?

Comment: Here's a better screenshot of the errors that are generated using the above: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8gi67ulcjuldm4k/Screenshot%202016-10-05%2012.24.48.png?dl=0 and https://www.dropbox.com/s/t9ks7d02coycicb/Screenshot%202016-10-05%2012.26.34.png?dl=0